# how to move lips in human imported from make human

Tags: rigging, bones, makehuman

I have imported the human into bender tool. I want the lip movement to happen in that human, can you please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rig the model for mouth movement.  One way to do this is to use PitchiPoy version of rigify, which adds facial animation.  There is a [tutorial](http://pitchipoy.tv/rigify-addon-for-blender-pitchipoy-version-tutorial/) from PitchiPoy, but I haven't tried it.